# Acceder a varios archivos de un carpeta con fstream

Tags: c++, fstream

Estoy llevando a cabo un programa el cual me pide recorrer varios archivos que están en una carpeta específica (son como 500 archivos). Ya logré leer un archivo mediante `fstream`, pero me gustaría ver si hay alguna manera de acceder  a la carpeta para acceder a los nombres y que se fuera leyendo uno por uno.

Éste es el código que estoy ocupando para leer un archivo:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void lectura ();

int main(){
    lectura();
    system("pause");
    return 0;

}

void lectura(){
    ifstream archivo;
    string texto;
    archivo.open("003.html",ios::in); //abre el rachivo

    if(archivo.fail()){
        cout<<" No se pudo abrir el archivo";
        exit(1);
    }

    while(!archivo.eof()){
        getline(archivo,texto);
        cout<<texto<<endl;
    }
    archivo.close();

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si puedes compilar bajo el estándar C++17 (estándar bastante moderno que no estará disponible en todos los compiladores) puedes hacer uso de la librería `filesystem` para inspeccionar el directorio en busca del tan ansiado listado de ficheros. Si puedes compilar bajo C++14 es posible que tengas disponible esta librería de forma *experimental*:

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::string path = "ruta_del_directorio";
  for (auto & p : std::filesystem::directory_iterator(path))
    std::cout << p << std::endl;
}
```

Si no es tu caso y puedes hacer uso de `boost`, puedes probar con algo así:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  boost::filesystem::path p ("ruta_del_directorio");

  boost::filesystem::directory_iterator end_itr;

  for (boost::filesystem::directory_iterator itr(p); itr != end_itr; ++itr)
  {
    if (boost::filesystem::is_regular_file(itr->path())) {
      std::string current_file = itr->path().string();
      std::cout << current_file << endl;
    }
  }
}
```

Y si no es posible ninguna de estas posibilidades entonces tienes que tirar de librerías de terceros o de soluciones a medida de tu sistema operativo. Por ejemplo para linux puedes usar esto:

```
#include <string>
#include <dirent.h>

if( DIR* pDIR = opendir("ruta_del_directorio") )
{
  while(dirent* entry = readdir(pDIR))
  {
    std::string fileName = entry->d_name;

    if( fileName != "." && fileName != ".." )
      std::cout << fileName << '\n';
  }
  closedir(pDIR);
}
```